# Finite-dimensional complex representation of finitely-generated abelian group - completely reducible?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, abelian-groups

My question might be a bit naive. I'm a bit rusted when it comes to representation theory and I'd like to know whether there is a quick argument which answers my question...

So, suppose we have a finitely-generated abelian group and a finite-dimensional complex representation of it. Is it completely reducible?

Comment: Not necessarily if the group is infinite. Think of the $2 \times 2$ upper unitriangular integral matrices as a representation of ${\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: Hm, I see... Well, I need it for some application in physics. Like, I have a translation group and want to show that I can decompose the eigenspace of my Hamiltonian into eigenspaces of my translations... and thought I could employ some formal argument there...

Comment: If the generators, as individual matrices, act semisimply (i.e. they are diagonalizable), then they are simultaneously diagonalizable (a commuting set of diagonalizable matrices is simultaneously diagonalizable). Therefore the representation is completely reducible (to a direct sum of 1-dimensional reps). I don't know if the individual translations you need to work with are diagonalizable, so I don't know if this helps you. Observe that the matrices in Derek Holt's example are not diagonalizable.

Comment: In other words, if the restrictions of your representation to all cyclic subgroups are completely reducible, then the representation is itself completely reducible.

Comment: I see, well, I don't think I have that given...
But it helps me to improve my understanding. Seems like it is not possible to make such a strong statement, the way I imagined.